# How to get loggers in java.util.logging so i can change their log level at runtime?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am using `java.util.logging` in different classes. The Log Level's default value is `INFO`. For example in one class `Class1` it is setup this way:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Class1 {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Class1.class.getName());
   static {
       LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
       for (Handler handler : LOGGER.getHandlers()) {
           handler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
       }           
   }
   ...
}
```

The above is the same way it is setup in different classes.

Now the Log Level could be changed at runtime. For example suppose it is changed to `FINEST` at runtime. In this case I want to get all the loggers which have been created so far and then change their Log Level to `FINEST`. How can I do that? I was thinking about creating another class say `LogRepository` which has a `java.util.List` and whenever a LOGGER is created, I add it into the `java.util.List` of `LogRepository`. But I think there may be another better way.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something  which is not done by Log4j's LoggerRepository class as mentioned here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerRepository.html#getCurrentLoggers() ?

Comment: I have not used Log4j but looking at your link I agree that I am looking for something like `getCurrentLoggers()` method on `java.util.logging` side. Why you said **not done** in your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a matter of setting the level of the parent logger that all of the instances inherit from.

```
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
```

Comment: So `Logger.getLogger("")` will give me parent of all loggers?

Comment: There is mention of the name "" being synonymous with the root logger, but only in the JavaDocs of the `getAnonymousLogger()` method:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getAnonymousLogger()

Comment: I think they should have a method called `getRootLogger()` instead. Would be much easier to understand.

Comment: agreed. And while they're at it, they should add `debug`, `trace`, and `error` methods, too!